# Unable to bind data using double curly braces in a Vuejs and systemjs set up

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, typescript, systemjs, vue.js

I have an ASP.net mvc project where I'm using Vuejs with typescript to render parts of one of my  pages. The problem is I cant get my data to show up in the view using double curly braces but when I use `v-text` it works. i.e this works: `<span v-text="name"></span>`, but this doesnt work: `{{name}}` .

I feel it has something to do with my Systemjs config because when i call a sample js file directly in a script tag, I dont get this problem, but when I use systemjs for the same sample file, problem comes back.

Without SystemJs and works:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/Admin/Content/js/vuejs/EditProductVariantsController.js"></script>
```

With Systemjs and doesn't work:

```
 SystemJS.config({
    packages: {
        '/Areas/Admin/Content/js/vuejs': {
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            map: {
                'Vue': '/Areas/Admin/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js'
            }
        }
    }
});

SystemJS.import("/Areas/Admin/Content/js/vuejs/EditProductVariantsController.js");
```

and this is my vuejs code:

```
var Vue = require("Vue");

new Vue({
  el: "#edit-product-variants",
  data: { name: "Mudi" }
});
```

My page requires me to get some values that wont be rendered using `{{}}` and not `v-text` e.g "id" and index in a `v-for` block.

Since I'm using typescript, I'm forced to use a module loader hence my use of SystemJs. Please Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out there was also `AngularJs` in the project and it was having the problem because both `AngularJs` and `VueJs` use the curly braces. So when I take Angular out of the project, everything works fine.